# Show that every number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I am not even sure where to start with this one. I understand for something to be a limit then that means if we have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of irrational numbers then for any number $a$ in the reals, the $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$. But how would you show that any number fulfils this statement?

Comment: Do you know that the irrationals are also dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4):

We assume that you already know that every real number is the limit of a sequence of rationals.

Let $x$ be real, and let $y=x-\sqrt{2}$. Then there is a sequence $(r_n)$ of rationals with limit $y$. It follows that the sequence $(\sqrt{2}+r_n)$ of irrationals has limit $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: show first there is an irrational number in $(x,y)$ for $x<y$. Then, apply this to $(a-\frac{1}{n},a)$ to obtain a sequence that converges to $a$.

Comment: should it be (x - 1/n, x + 1/n)? Why is it just (x- 1/n, x)?

Comment: Both work. You can pick either.