# Show every number $\in\mathbb{R}$ is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> Show that every number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers

---

Proof:

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is dense of $\mathbb{R}$, then for the sequence of irrational numbers $\{a_n\}$, each members of $\{a_n\}\in(a-1/n,a+1/n)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now let $\epsilon>0$, then by the Archimedean Property, there exists an index $N$ such that $1/N<\epsilon$. And for all $n\geq N$, we can get $1/n\leq1/N$. So $$|a_n-a|\leq 1/n\leq 1/N<\epsilon$$

Thus $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a$.

---

I found a same question [Show that every number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960289/show-that-every-number-is-the-limit-of-a-sequence-of-irrational-numbers) and seems I am doing the same thing from the hit provided by Kim Jong Un. Can anyone check my proof right or not ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're trying to approach things is WAY overkill. Just give the sequences.

If $a$ is rational, let $a_n=a+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ (or pick your favorite irrational number).

If $a$ is irrational, let $a_n=a$.

Comment: If I separated bu these two cases, I can easily apply Archimedean Property, right?

Comment: @Simple All you need to show is that the first converges to $a$, to do this you use Archimedian Property. You are 100% correct. :)

Answer (score 3):

For any real $a$,
let
$a_n
=\frac1{n}\lfloor n\,a \rfloor +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
|a_n-a|
&=|\frac1{n}\lfloor n\,a \rfloor+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}-a|\\
&=\frac1{n}|\lfloor n\,a \rfloor-n\,a+\sqrt{2}|\\
&\le \frac1{n}(1+\sqrt{2})
\end{array}
$

since
$|\lfloor n\,a \rfloor-n\,a|
\le 1
$.

Note that,
to get *rational* approximations,
just remove the
$\sqrt{2}$ part.